# How to validate only specific routes/subpaths using express-openapi-validator?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, validation, openapi

I have an express server that I want to validate against an OpenAPI spec. All the [documentation](https://cdimascio.github.io/express-openapi-validator-documentation/) for `express-openapi-validator` only provides examples of validating all routes with `app.use(OpenApiValidator.middleware())`.

However, for a server with many subpaths, I want to only validate some and not others. Let's say, I only want to validate the path `example.com/subpath1/subSubpath1`, and only after some checks and assigning needed body parser.

This is my current setup:

```js
const app : express.Express = express();
app.use('/subpath1', getSubpathOneRouter()); // part of this needs validation
app.use('/subpath2', getSubpathTwoRouter()); // doesn't need validation

export function getSubpathOneRouter() : express.Router {
    let subpathOneRouter = express.Router();
    
    subpathOneRouter.post('/subSubpath1',
        async (req, res, next) => {
            await somethingCustom(req, res, next, somethingElse);
        },
        express.json(),
        // VALIDATION SHOULD HAPPEN HERE
        async (req, res, next) => { res.sendStatus(200); }
    );

    // No validation needed for this one
    subpathOneRouter.get('/subSubpath2',
        async (req, res, next) => { /* whatever */ },
    );

    return subpathOneRouter;
}
```

How would I achieve validation only on that specific subpath?